# How can I initialize with a constructor an object from another class?

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

I'm new at learning c++ and a have stuck in constructors.I have a class `Teacher` and a Class `Subject`. In class `Teacher` a have an object `Subject S[]`. How I can initialize with constructor from class `Teacher` the `S[]`? I have tried this:
in Teacher.h file

```
class Teacher 
{
  private:
    string name;
    Subject *S[20];
  public:
    Teacher();
}
```

in Teacher.cpp file

```
Teacher::Teacher()
{
  name=" ";
  for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
  {
    S[i].Subject();
  }
}
```

in Subject.cpp file the Constructor is:

```
Subject::Subject()
{
  day=0;
  hour=0;
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
    classroom[i]=" ";
  }
}
```

Comment: these are the basics, get hold of a good book and practice.

Answer (score 1):

The way you currently have it, you'd have to write

`S[i] = new Subject();`

rather than

`S[i].Subject();`

But that burdens you with having to remember to call `delete` at some point. It would be *far* better to use

`std::list<Subject> S;`

in place of

`Subject *S[20];`

and then `push_back` or even the flashier `emplace_back` in place of `S[i].Subject();`

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list

Comment: Any reason why not `std::vector`?

Comment: To me a list seems more of a natural container to model a list of subjects.

Comment: I'd say it's impossible to say which container is more natural as long as we don't know which operations will be needed. For example, if subjects will actually be removed while iterators to other elements should remain valid.

Answer (score 1):

> In class Teacher a have an object Subject S[]

No you dont:

> ```
> Subject *S[20];
> ```

`Teacher::S` is an array of pointers.

> ```
> S[i].Subject();
> ```

`.` is used for member access. Pointers do not have members, so this is syntactically wrong. Besides, you never call a constructor directly. It is called automatically as a consequence of initializing a variable, or a *new expression*.

---

It seems that to want to have an array of `Subject` objects as a member instead. This is how you would declare such member:

```
Subject S[20];
```

The objects in the array will be constructed before the body of `Teacher` constructor is executed.

Comment: The problem with a fixed array is that there is always a girlyswot who takes 21 subjects.

Comment: @Bathsheba true. The greatest advantage of using a statically sized array is that one will quickly learn to appreciate dynamic data structures, when one eventually learns of them.

Comment: Ok I changed the declaration of Subject to `Subject S[20];` but in the teacher constructor `S[i].Subject();` doesn't work.

Comment: @user5624945 as I said, *The objects in the array will be constructed before the body of `Teacher` constructor is executed.*. You cannot call the constructor of an object that has already been constructed. Simply remove the loop.